# Use list.size() or a variable for multiple use ? (local optimization)

Tags: java, list, optimization, size

I have a simple function called a lot.

Inside this function, I have many calls to the size of a list (containing around 10 elements):

```
list.size()
```

Is it faster for me to use a temporary variable to **get the size only once**, or is it faster to **call the `size()` method every time**?

**Update**: it's an `ArrayList`.

*Note: I know what I am doing, I am not looking for a lecture regarding optimization and how it should or shouldn't be done. I am just looking for an answer.*

Comment: Could you benchmark the function?

Comment: @Asaf: It really ins't practical for me, I've done it for other things but here there is too much business logic, that would an overkill given many people probably know this answer already (look at the answers, it seems to be the case)

Comment: Even in a micro-benchmark with a tirivla loop you will have trouble telling the difference, if there is "too much business logic" you can be certain that `size()` is not going to make much if any difference.  Are you sure the method has been compiled when it is running? This can make 10x difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on implementation of the `List`
Looking at the `ArrayList`'s source

```
/**
  225        * Returns the number of elements in this list.
  226        *
  227        * @return the number of elements in this list
  228        */
  229       public int size() {
  230           return size;
  231       }
  232
```

So it doesn't matter if you take a local variable or call this method

Comment: +1: for reference. Could You also include `LinkedList.size()`? I believe it was O(N) or so.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my question, it was indeed an ArrayList, I should have said that directly, thank you for providing this code!

Comment: @Rekin its same implementation in [`size()`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/LinkedList.java.html)

Answer (score 10):

It entirely depends on the implementation. You haven't specified the type of `list` - I assume it's a `List<E>` or some concrete implementation.

In some implementations such as `ArrayList<E>` it's extremely cheap - a field access, basically. It's only *documented* in terms of being constant time, admittedly:

> The `size`, `isEmpty`, `get`, `set`, `iterator`, and `listIterator` operations run in constant time.

In others it *could* potentially be expensive. The interface doesn't provide any guarantees. I would expect it to be cheap (constant time) in *most* implementations, but you never know for sure...

Comment: @Matthieu: In that case, it's cheap.

Answer (score 4):

Check this out (from `ArrayList` and also `LinkedList`):

```
/**
 * Returns the number of elements in this list.
 *
 * @return the number of elements in this list
 */
public int size() {
return size;
}
```

Calling `list.size()` is about as efficient as invoking a method and putting a value on the stack: (almost) negligible. Of course you'll be a tiny bit faster using a local (`final`) variable. If this is an important improvement in the context of your application or not, you will probably have to measure.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how fast `size()` method call is. It's a good practice to introduce a variable to carry the result of the method, if that method is invoked multiple times inside a block of code, assuming that the method doesn't change anything.

Comment: I disagree. I'm perfectly happy with writing `for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)` in cases where the enhanced for loop won't work. I consider this to be more immediately readable than extracting a local variable - and readability is critical in more situations than performance is, IMO.

Comment: I also think that readability is more important rather than optimising almost negligible overheads. After all, the Java-5 foreach loop also has a slight overhead introduced by compiler-generated code, but is much more readable than manually managing iterators...